# Posso postar exercícios resolvidos aqui?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Quando comecei a programar tive muita dificuldade de colocar no papel o que as questões pediam, saía pela web caçando exemplos para me ajudar nas questões de lógica e sintaxe, não queria copiar, queria ver como os programadores haviam pensado sobre aquelas questões, acredito que observar os exemplos, em programação, é uma ótima forma de aprendizado, então, posso postar questões e como resolvê-las aqui? Em visualG, que é uma linguagem genérica e pode ser traduzida para qualquer outra linguagem?

Answer (score 7):

O exercício em si não é problema. A intenção do que quer pode ser. Postar o exercício e pedir para as pessoas resolverem ele para você não é adequado e é considerado implicitamente como fora de escopo porque não é um problema específico, é ter que solucionar todo o problema para a pessoa. Algumas pessoas até disfarçam um pouco, mas ainda é pedir para a pessoa resolver para ela.

Há alguns casos que está tão bem disfarçado que até passa. Mas há casos que está lá o exercício definido, o que a pessoa já tentou (e ela tentou, ela mostrou esforço, realmente fez um trabalho para resolver, mas algo está dando errado), e aí ela tem um problema específico. Em geral a comunidade até aceita ser tiver alguns problemas específicos juntos. E aí tanto faz se aquilo é exercício ou não.

Existem casos que a pessoa precisa realizar algo que não é um exercício e ela vem e pede para fazer para ela, e não é aceito, então o problema não é ser exercício. E não adianta dizer que não pediu para fazer tudo para ele, afinal só não fazer o pedido explicitamente não faz ficar melhor. O mesmo vale para quase qualquer coisa que a pessoa posta um código e diz "alguém pode me ajudar" ou "podem me dar uma luz", isto é quase certo que não tem um problema específico ali. Pode até ser só falta de clareza da resposta ou porque tem algo muito amplo.

Se sua intenção é postar a pergunta e resposta, não tem problemas algum, isso é incentivado, porém a pergunta poderia ser respondida normalmente por qualquer usuário? Isto pode fazer diferença, porque perguntas com resposta do autor dela precisa ser feita com cuidado, tem que ter mais certeza que ela tem tudo o que é necessário para qualquer um chegara ali entender e poder responder. Perguntas que só o autor pode responder não são adequadas. E se é só o enunciado do exercício cai no mesmo problema anterior.

Porém se coloca a resposta na hora a pessoa não quer que faça para ele. Aí eu penso que poderia se pensar se não é útil, é um bom debate, e outras pessoas podem dar opinião se seria uma boa exceção aceitar isso já que o objetivo é diferente.

Mas fico pensando, será que a pessoa fará bem? Será que a resposta é boa? Será que isto não trará mais problema porque a pessoa deu a solução dela, mas será que ela não está só aprendendo e ainda não sabe dar uma boa resposta? Será que não servirá apenas como um repositório de exercícios resolvidos para outras pessoas consultarem e copiarem?

Pra mim o maior problema da pessoa postar par de pergunta e resposta é que muitas pessoas não fazem com intenção de ser uma pergunta válida, e sim só o veículo para a resposta, só ela pode responder. A intenção é boa, mas não é um trabalho pensando na comunidade.

O site não precisa ser perfeito, mas precisamos analisar bem se aceitar este tipo de conteúdo trará mais problemas que soluções.